# Attaining desired input snr in noisy signal

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, noise

I have taken a clean speech signal and need to get an input SNR of 0dB, 5dB and 10dB by adding certain amount of white noise.
Can anyone explain what 0dB, 5dB... is? Is it the power of white noise in the command

```
noise=wgn(1,20115,0);
```

and if not, how do I achieve input SNR of 0dB, 5dB and 10dB?

Comment: This is not a programming question, but rather a signal processing question.

Answer (score 0):

The signal to noise ratio (SNR) is the signal power relative to the noise power. The easiest way to achieve a given SNR while adding White Gaussian Noise to a clean signal is with [`awgn`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/awgn.html):

```
input_snr_db = 5; % Choose input SNR in dB
noisy_signal = awgn(clean_signal, input_snr_db, 'measured');
```

This computes the required level of noise given a signal which may not have unitary power.